# Number of faces on sphere Marker (RVIZ)

Tags: rviz, ogre, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

I'm wondering if there is some easy way to increase the number of faces plot on RVIZ when, as an example, displaying a visualization_msgs::Marker::SPHERE. I suspect that it's an Ogre issue rather an Rviz setting..

Have a look to this pic https://farm9.staticflickr.com/8648/15895679946_3e7e039afb_c.jpg

[image: image description]

Any thoughts?

Bye, Augusto

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/284139/number-of-faces-on-sphere-marker-(rviz)/) by [Augusto Luis Ballardini](https://answers.ros.org/users/234/augusto-luis-ballardini/) on ROS Answers with karma: 430 on 2018-03-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Got it. The mesh is located under:

```
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/rviz/ogre_media/models/rviz_sphere.mesh
```

or your cloned repository under the models folder and it is loaded from [shape.cpp](https://github.com/ros-visualization/rviz/blob/kinetic-devel/src/rviz/ogre_helpers/mesh_shape.cpp) (github link)

The only issue is to create a new mesh, which can actually be done using Blender and some tools. I used:

- blender-2.79a-linux-glibc219-x86_64 ; from blender, I've created the new sphere (just press the Create tab and then Sphere, then click F6 to change the number of "faces".  Then Export > Ogre3D (activate the add-on following the instructions of blender2ogre). Save the sphereHD.mesh.xml
- blender2ogre [blender2ogre](https://github.com/OGRECave/blender2ogre) (follow install instructions from the readme)
- [OgreXmlConverter](http://wiki.ogre3d.org/OgreXmlConverter) only for windows :-( Use it to convert the sphereHD.mesh.xml to something that Ogre is able to use. Then "change the filename under shape.cpp and compile RVIZ again". Ok it's not the best solution I know, but that's a start :-)

Some images:

From Blender...

[image: image description]

Sphere rendered inside RVIZ before:

[image: image description]

Sphere rendered inside RVIZ afteR:
[image: image description]

I've also used as reference:
https://answers.ros.org/question/9770/display-an-ogre-mesh-and-material-in-rviz/
https://github.com/OGRECave/blender2ogre
http://wiki.ogre3d.org/OgreXmlConverter
http://wiki.ogre3d.org/Blender+to+Ogre

---

Originally posted by [Augusto Luis Ballardini](https://answers.ros.org/users/234/augusto-luis-ballardini/) with karma: 430 on 2018-03-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0